# Javascript Should I store a reference to a nested object or use it directly?

Tags: javascript, reference

I assume this has almost no performance impact if you go with either of them, but I was wondering what if it is better to use one or the other.

Given I have:

```
    var a = { b: {c: { d: ... }}};
    var ref = a.b.c.d;
```

Should I use a.b.c.d directly or create and use a reference, here named 'ref'?

And furthermore if there is a getter function that returns an object with several levels of complexity:

```
    var a = { b: {c: { d: ... }}};
    function getObject() {
      return a;
    }
    var ref = getObject();
```

Is there a difference between getObject().b.c.d and ref?

I know it is not that important, but my OCD doesn't allow me to put it to rest. :D

Comment: Both snippets have different purposes, yet, are doing the same thing. If you don't need the `getObject()`, then why would you create it at the first place?

Comment: Property access like that has a (tiny) overhead. Directly accessing the `d` will be faster. Now the point is: when is that overhead larger than the overhead of declaring a new variable? In the end, chose what you are most comfortable with. Neither will result in a noticeable performance difference.

Comment: Nanoseconds do not matter. If they matter, write assembly.

Comment: @JonasW: That question is iPhone-specifc.

Comment: @JonasW.: Or find one that specifically discusses this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Javascript Should I store a reference to a nested object or use it directly?

That depends almost entirely on the specific situation. In general, write whatever code is *clearest*, rather than worrying about efficiency, until/unless you have a performance problem in front of you that you need to solve.

#### Re your first snippet:

Accessing properties on objects takes non-zero time, but it's **very** efficient on modern browsers. So using `ref` instead of `a.b.c.d` will be faster, but it's unlikely to matter in any code you're writing unless you're doing it hundreds of thousands of times in a row in a tight loop. Worry about that if and when you're doing that.

The other thing to consider is whether other code may modifiy `a`, or `b`, or `c`, such that `ref === a.b.c.d` is no longer true. If you want your code to see those changes, don't use `ref`. If you want it protected from such a change, use `ref`, even though `ref` may be out of date.

#### Re your second snippet:

There's a big difference: You're not calling `getObject` later if you use `ref` instead. If you know that you want to keep using the object `getObject` returned to you initially, and/or you want to avoid the overhead of repeating the call, use `ref`. But presumably `getObject` exists for a reason, so in some cases it may make more sense to use `getObject` again. It really varies depending on the details of the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Property access like that has a (tiny) overhead.
Directly accessing the `d` by using a `ref` variable will be faster.

Now the point is: when is the property access overhead larger than the overhead of declaring a new variable?
In the end, chose what you are most comfortable with. Neither will result in a noticeable performance difference.